# How to restore GRUB after restoring Debian from backup?

Tags: debian, grub2, backup, restore

I need to make a backup my Debian VPS server and create it copies on Virtual Machines. I'm following instructions on page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR.

Steps:

- I've done a tar archive of entire OS,
- I've copied it into host machine,
- I've created Debian virtual machine,
- I've booted Debian 8 Jessie livecd on VM,
- I've partitioned a disk,
- I've mounted root partition on `/mnt`,
- I've entered to dir `/mnt`,
- I've copied `backup.tar.gz` over ssh to `/mnt`,
- I've extracted archive `backup.tar.gz` in `/mnt`,
- I've executed command `for f in dev dev/pts proc ; do mount --bind /$f /mnt/$f ; done`,
- I've chrooted into `/mnt`,
- I've executed command `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`,
- I've mounted /dev/sda1 in `/boot`,
- I've executed `grub-install /dev/sda`.

I'm giving an `device node not found` error at last step:

```
root@debian:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to mount `/sys` on to `/mnt`.

Comment: Now I'm getting `WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.` while executing `update-grub2` from chroot.

Comment: Do blkid and check that id exists in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: I don't see why that warning is a problem assuming boot is not on lvm

Comment: Grub boots into command line mode instead of graphical mode.

Comment: Okay, but is it booting Linux now?

Comment: Yep, I've already solved this problem alone.